# tableView's insertRowsAtIndexPath doesn't call tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with an Edit button. When this is clicked, the user can delete or add rows to the UITableView. Deleting rows works fine. But when I want to add a new row, I get a short animation of an empty cell coming from the left and when the animation is over, the table view looks exactly as it looked before the method was called. When I add a new cell, I add a new object to the data array that feeds my table view and then add the cell. That data array gets updated. So if I call `[tableView reloadData]` after I have added the new cell, I get to see the new cell but without any animation. And I really would like to have the animation as well.

I have a working example of the same thing. I realized that after `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` gets called, the table view's data source method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets automatically called. In my case, it doesn't. I guess that's the reason why I'm not seeing the new cell. Any ideas why this is happening?

This is my `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:self.tableData forKey:self.key];
        [defaults synchronize];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];
        NSString *textFieldText = [textField text];
        if (textFieldText != nil) 
        {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:textFieldText];
            [self.tableData addObject:string];
            [string release];

            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:self.tableData forKey:self.key];
            [defaults synchronize];

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];   

            // If reloadData is being called, the new cell is displayed but without the animation
            // [tableView reloadData]; 
        } 
        else
        {
            // Display alert view
            // Code for displaying an AlertView
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try sending a call to `super` and see what happens.  You may be inadvertently bypassing some parent class functionality.

Comment: If I call [super tableView:tableView commitEditingStyle:editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath], I get an exception. Or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your insert call with [tableView beginUpdates] [tableView endUpdates]. From the docs:

> If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls
>   inside this block, table attributes such as row count might become
>   invalid.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That sounded promising but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try uncommenting your reloadData call after endUpdates?

Comment: I noticed, though, that if I do [tableView reloadData] after the code you posted, then I get some kind of animation. The animation is a bit different than it should be (maybe shorter) but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be adding the new string into the array at the index that matches indexPath.row?

Comment: [indexPath row] is always the last row since the "add item" cell with the green plus sign is located at the end. So the new string index should correspond the [indexPath row].

Comment: Even though, this didn't solve my problem completely, this is the best approach I could find. At least I get a small animation with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same issue. From what I can tell, the UITableView only calls cellForRowAtIndexPath if it thinks the cell being changed is visible. Since you are adding a new cell I'm guessing the table does not think it's visible and therefore does not call the method. Jaminguys solution works for me, but it sounds a bit like a bug in UIKit.

This method does work if you are inserting cells in the middle of the table view, incidentally.